# Algorithm for maximal hypervolume simplex

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

Given a set of points in **D**-dimensional space. What is the optimal algorithm to find maximal possible **D**-simplex, all the vertexes of which is in the set? Algebraically it means that we have to find a subset of **D + 1** points such, that determinant of **D * D** matrix, constructed from rows as deltas of coordinates each of first **D** points and last **D + 1**-st point, have greatest possible value (absolute value) on the set.

I sure, that all **D + 1** required points are vertexes of convex hull of given set of points, but I need the algorithm, which not used any convex hull algorithm, because simplex required for they, in turn, required for such algorithms as starting polytope.

If it is not possible to obtain the simplex in less than exponential time, then what is the algorithm, which gives adjustable ratio *run-time/precision of approximation* for approximate solving of the problem?

Comment: You are using "**D**" inconsistently.  Is **D** the number of dimensions or is **D** the dimensional space itself?

Comment: @Orient can you provide us with some examples, reading this makes things complicated

Comment: @Amir special for you: given a set of (x_i,y_i), i in {1..N} points. Please, propose the algorithm, which gives maximal-square triangle with vertexes from this set of points. Algorithm must be generalizable for higher dimensions.

Comment: Are you solving a homework problem or do you actually want to do this?

Comment: @tmyklebu Do not worry. I am not student.

Comment: @Orient: Not what I was getting at; if it's a homework problem then it's plenty hard.  Are you asking for an algorithm that you can prove bounds about (or an NP-completeness result), or are you asking for something that 'works' in practise?

Comment: @tmyklebu Sure, something, that works in practice. I trying to implement a quick hull algorithm, and I need approach to give a good initial simplex.

Comment: @Orient: Aha.  Why not just select the initial simplex randomly?  It's not clear to me that volume is the right thing to look at, since it's not an invariant of a hyperplane arrangement.  This problem looks hard, though a reduction isn't coming to mind immediately.

Comment: @tmyklebu {(0.0001, 0), (0.0002, 0), (0.0003, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)}. At least we should to choose a minmax coordinates.

Comment: You should have specified "maximal volume" for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an exact solution, but you could probably get a reasonable approximation with an iterative approach. Note than I'm assuming that `N` is larger than `D+1` here; if not then I have misunderstood the problem.

First, use a greedy algorithm to construct an initial simplex; choose the first two vertices to be the two most distant points, the next one to maximise your size measure in two dimensions, the next to maximise it in three, and so on. This has polynomial complexity in `N` and `D`.
One you have the initial simplex you can switch to iterative improvement. For example, for a given vertex in the simplex you can iterate through the points not in it measuring the change in the size measure that would result if you swapped them. At the end you swap it with the one, if any, that gave the greatest increase. Doing this once for each vertex in the simplex is again polynomial in `N` and `D`.
To trade-off betwen run-time cost and how large the resulting simplex is, simply choose how many times you're willing to do this.

Now this is a relatively crude *local* optimisation algorithm so cannot guarantee that it will find the maximal simplex. However, such approaches have been found to result in reasonably good approximations to the solution of problems like the travelling salesman problem, in the sense that whilst they're not optimal, they result in a distance that isn't too much greater than that of the actual solution in most cases.

Comment: Yes, N is larger then D. Moreover, every D + 1 points is linearly independent (without loss of generality).

Answer (score 1):

Quickhull does not require to find a maximal simplex, this is overkill (too hard a problem, and will not guarantee that the next steps will be quicker).

I suggest you to select **D+1** independent directions and take the farthest point in every direction. This will give you a good starting simplex in time `O(N.D²)`. (The `D²` is because there are `D+1` directions and evaluation of the distance in a direction takes `D` operations.)

Beware anyway that it can be degenerate (several vertexes being identical).

Comment: The same as implemented in original `qhull`.

Answer (score 0):

My own approximation of the solution is to take one point, compute furhtest from it and reject first point (totally `N=1` point selected), then select else `D - 1` points in such manner, that non-oriented `N - 1`-dimensional hypervolume ([formula for `S`](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/828854/54348)) of each `N`-points selection is maximal. Finally I find `N = D + 1`'st point it the way, that oriented `D` dimensional hypervolume ([formula for `V`](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/828854/54348)) of defined simplex is maximal by absolute value. Total complexity on my mind is something about `O(D * N * D^3)` (`1...D + 1` vertices of simplex, `N...N - D - 1` remaining points and `D^3` is upper estimate of `D * M, M in {1,2,...,D}` matrix multiplication complexity). The approach allows us to find the right amount of linearly independent points, or else to find a dimension of the subspace and non-normalized and non-orthogonal basis of the subspace. For large amount of points and large dimensionalities the complexity of proposed algorithm does not predominate over the complexity of, say, *quickhull* algorithm.

[The implementation's repository](https://bitbucket.org/tomilov/quickhull).